# Access of file on desktop using C++

Tags: c++

I am using Windows 7   and I have created on the desktop a file named  `test.txt`.    How can I  access this  file using C++? For example,  consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  fstream inout("test.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

  if(!inout) {
    cout << "Cannot open input file.\n";
    return 1;
  }

  long e, i, j;
  char c1, c2;
  e = 5;

  for(i=0, j=e; i<j; i++, j--) {
    inout.seekg(i, ios::beg);
    inout.get(c1);
    inout.seekg(j, ios::beg);
    inout.get(c2);

    inout.seekp(i, ios::beg);
    inout.put(c2);
    inout.seekp(j, ios::beg);
    inout.put(c1);
  }

  inout.close();
  return 0;
}
```

In the fragment `fstream inout("test.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary)`, what should I change to access   my test.txt on desktop?

Comment: Just specify a full path to the file.

Comment: By the way...  There will be several suggestions to just put the full path in.  But it will help to know that you have to double the backslashes in the path:  "c:\\some\\directory\\here" and also put a backslash in front of any spaces in the path: "c:\\my\ favorite\ directory\\has\\neat\ stuff\\in\ it".

Comment: Since it's a text file, why `ios::binary`?  Are you going to handle it as text or as a stream of unrelated bytes?

Comment: @EricTowers: You don't have to escape spaces in paths. You do have to escape spaces though when they are interepreted, e.g. by a commandline shell, but that's not the case here.

Answer (score 8):

Are you asking how to access that file location from your program? If so, you need to put the file and the executable in the same directory, or include a full path to the file's location:

```
"%USERPROFILE%\\Desktop\\test.txt"
```

Unless there is a full file path starting from a drive letter (the variable %USERPROFILE% evaluates to C:\Users\ {your username} in your case) the executable will look for the file relative to its own location. Since your string contains only the file name, it will look in its own directory.

Comment: Actually `%USERPROFILE%` evaluates to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` and `%HOMEPATH%` expands based on the particular OS version. On XP it's `\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%[.%USERDOMAIN%]`. But anyway.. *big* +1 for not just putting `C:\...` like most of the other answers.

Comment: OP mentioned Windows 7 so I assumed it was the typical setup. Just trying to explain what the variable meant without going into too much detail.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the full path to the file. Determine what the absolute path is for the file and use that in the first argument:

```
fstream inout("c:\\some\\whole\\path\\to\\docmument\\test.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use ifstream, that is
`ifstream inputfile("\path\to\input\file`);
What path it is is easiest seen using your explorer or whatever it is called these days.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to provide the abosolute path to `test.text`, which can be something like (I'm not sure):

```
C:\WINDOWS\Desktop\test.txt
```

Comment: In Win7 it's "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop"

Comment: Yes, "Users" was a much better choice than "Documents and Settings".

Comment: But since it can vary ("Documents and Settings" vs. "Users") then either choice is bad. It's also customizable and could be neither of those, and isn't even required to be on `C:`

Comment: Not to mention translated versions. Oh, and since it contains a username: don't assume the path is ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

The path to the desktop is available

```
#include <shlobj_core.h>

ofstream file;
TCHAR appData[MAX_PATH];
if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL,
            CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY | CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE,
            NULL,
            SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT,
            appData))) 
    {
        int Size = 0;
        string pathDesktop;
        while (appData[Size] != '\0') pathDesktop+= appData[Size++];
        pathDesktop+= "\\test.txt";
        file.open(pathDesktop);
      if (file.is_open())
      {  
          file << "Hello World";
          file.close();
      }
}
```