# why this code writes can't open file

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char *argv){
fstream inout("C:\\Users\\7\\Desktop\\test.txt",ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
if (!inout){
 cout<<" cannot open input file.\n";
  return 1;

}

long e,i,j;
char c1,c2;
e=5;
 for (i=0,j=e;i<j;i++,j--){


  inout.seekg(i,ios::beg);
  inout.get(c1);
  inout.seekg(j,ios::beg);
  inout.get(c2);
  inout.seekp(i,ios::beg);
  inout.put(c2);
  inout.seekg(j,ios::beg);
  inout.put(c1);
 }


 inout.close();



 return 0;
}
```

why this code writes can't open file
EDIT:
i have made  corrections    but here is one problem
in test.txt is written such thing

```
maiko
miyvarxar
shen
me
```

so it should write
me shen miyvarxar maiko
but it does not write anything
please help

Comment: change your cout line (cannot open input file) to print the error

Comment: Does this really need to be another question? It looks remarkably similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991004/access-of-file-using-c).

Comment: Windows File system (like all other modern file systems) now accepts "/" as the directory separator. If you use this in paths it makes the code more portable. Easier to read (as it is not an escape).

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me:

```
using namespace std;
int main() 
{ 
  fstream inout("C:\\Users\\turdfurguson\\Turds\testfile.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
  if (inout.good())
    cout << "OK!" << endl;
}
```

Provided you have a "C:\Users\turdfurgson\Turds\testfile.txt" file that is readable and writable.

Comment: my dekstop full path is this   C:\Users\7\Desktop>   please help me

Comment: does the "test.txt" file exists?

Comment: try ", ios::in | ios::binary); what is result?

Comment: Oh man, I almost want to +1 you for your name and path choice.

Answer (score 0):

*The code you've provided looks fine.*

You may have supplied the wrong path or something like that.

You could also try attempting to open that file in read only mode
and see if that is ok:

```
std::ifstream in("path", std::ios::binary);

if (!in) {
   // fail
}
```